# TcpClient ConnectAsync with multiple IP addresses - what's the behavior?

Tags: .net, tcpclient

(context: a service provides monitoring capabilities to external web sites; customer provides a URL and we need to ping it; we're switching from HttpClient to TcpClient to provide visibility DNS/Connect/SSL/Send/Receive phases)

Here is a summary what code does:

```
IPHostEntry host = await Dns.GetHostEntryAsync(hostname).ConfigureAwait(false);
await this.client.ConnectAsync(host.AddressList, port).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

GetHostEntryAsync returns a list of IP addresses associated with a host.

What does TcpClient do with them? Does it try to establish a connection to the first, then if fails to the second, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It tries them one at a time](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/847a054cfd86f8ea828003197fda644a2fb20dbb/src/libraries/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.Tasks.cs#L152), and returns as soon as the first one succeeded or all have failed.